# Cakephp blank page on navigation to some actions

Tags: php, cakephp, action, whitespace, controllers

I am facing a problem since yesterday in cakephp . I want to believe that the problem comes from me , not the framework that I admire the simplicity . Since yesterday not view certain actions of my controllers in the browser: blank page. `  Here is an extract of my user controller code

```
// add action
public function admin_add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
          $file_manip =$this->request->data['User']['photo_file'];
        if(!empty( $file_manip['tmp_name'])){
    $extension_name = strtolower(pathinfo($file_manip['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $nom_fichier=$this->request->data['User']['surname'].rand(5,1000).'.'.$extension_name;
                if(in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($file_manip['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),array('jpeg','jpg','png'))){
                move_uploaded_file($file_manip['tmp_name'],IMAGES.'avatars'.DS.$nom_fichier);
                 $this->User->SaveField('photo',$nom_fichier);
                              }
                    }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    //$groups = $this->Group->find('list');
    $enseignes =$this->Enseigne->find('list');
    $villes = $this->Ville->find('list',array(
    'fields' => 'Ville.ville_nom',
    ));
    $this->set(compact('groups', 'villes','enseignes'));
}
```

I can reach this action without problem.
When i add  other action like:

```
    public function admin_gestion() {}
```

this doesn't work. I add the admin_gestion.ctp on the users folder, this file look like this:

```
<p>Bonjour je suis un test</p>
```

Nothing shows up, no error, just a blank page.
no error in log, no empty line before php tag, nothing, i set debug to 3, no error shows up. I dont know what to do! please help me

Comment: You should also mention the version of CakePHP. Your code looks like CakePHP 2.x so... [there is no debug level 3](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration)... Have you checked if other PHP files are working, outside CakePHP?

Comment: hi, yes i'm working on cakephp 2.X, i follow all advise i found on forum this is why i put degub to "3" but that change nothing. What do you mean by  "other php files are working outside cakephp" ? thank you for your answer

Comment: Debug level in core.php can only be 0,1or 2 (see the link to the book I posted). So you should change it to 2 and not to 3. If you don't get any error message, not even a 500 server error it sounds like a problem outside of CakePHP. Maybe you have got another issue with your server configuration. That's why I asked if other PHP files are working on the server... What is the name of your controller with the admin_gestion action? And how is your URL looking like when you try to open the page in your browser? Have you changed anything in the routing config file in CakePHP?

Comment: Why do you write "facing a problem since yesterday", did it work before? Have you checked all changes you made in between? Maybe you find the reason if you undo all changes step by step?

Comment: Hello, my debug mode is 2 actually, nothing happen. Yes my cakephp directory is a subdirectory of www, so many other projects are running in this directory using php. Yes it work before and when i put the action without admin prefix it work fine.What is weird is that add methode work with admin prefix but not other. Would you mind if I give you access to my ftp in private, in order to help me solve this issue. thank you again

Comment: Hi, i think i find the problem. It is about $this->Auth->allow(), when i add the action to this auth allow i can get access to it, but i'm asking myself why???